# Degree 1 divisor on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ over complex numbers.

> Is it true that any degree one divisor is linearly equivalent to $1.p$ for some point $p$?

I know it's true for $\mathbb P^1$. I am wondering if something like $p+q-r$ will be linearly equivalent to $p'$ on higher genus curves.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Only very rarely. The curve needs to be hyperelliptic.

Comment: Could you kindly sketch a proof? Also, is it iff? as in $C$ is hyperelliptic iff every degree 1 divisor is linearly equiv to $1.p$ for some $p$?

Comment: No, that was a response to your second question. You have a branched double cover of $\Bbb P^1$, so the preimages of different points (i.e., $p+p’$ where $p$ and $p’$ project to the same point) give linearly equivalent divisors.

Comment: The locus of degree $1$ divisor classes linearly equivalent to a point coincides with the image of the Abel--Jacobi map $C \to \mathrm{Jac}(C)$. But as $\dim \mathrm{Jac}(C) = g$, this map is not surjective for $g \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that $C$ is of genus $\le1$. Suppose for a contradiction that $g_C\ge2$. For any $x\ne y\in C$ we have $2x-y$ is a degree one divisor, so there is some point $p\in C$ such that $2x-y\sim p$. Thus there is a degree two rational function $f\colon C\to\mathbb P^1$ with zeroes $p$ and $y$ and a pole $x$ of multiplicity two. Thus, $C$ is a hyper-elliptic curve. Moreover, there are infinitely many rational functions $f\colon C\to\mathbb P^1$ giving a double cover.

But by Proposition 19.5.7 of Vakil, this is a contradiction.